# Winston not working with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, winston

I'm trying to use Winston in my React project but Webpack seems to be causing errors while building:

> WARNING in node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports.js
>   Critical dependencies:
>   23:17-34 the request of a dependency is an expression
>    @ node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports.js 23:17-34
>
> WARNING in node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js
>   Critical dependencies:
>   127:29-43 the request of a dependency is an expression
>    @ node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js 127:29-43
>
> WARNING in node_modules/colors/lib/extendStringPrototype.js
>   Critical dependencies:
>   106:31-45 the request of a dependency is an expression
>    @ node_modules/colors/lib/extendStringPrototype.js 106:31-45
>
> ERROR in node_modules/winston/lib/winston/common.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in node_modules/winston/lib/winston
>    @ node_modules/winston/lib/winston/common.js 12:9-22
>
> ERROR in node_modules/pkginfo/lib/pkginfo.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in node_modules/pkginfo/lib
>    @ node_modules/pkginfo/lib/pkginfo.js 8:9-22
>
> ERROR in node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports
>    @ node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/file.js 10:9-22

From what I've understood by digging around the problem is being caused by webpacks inability to deal with some dynamic require statements. Does anyone know a way around this or some solution to the same?

Comment: "webpacks inability to deal with some dynamic require statements" --- nope. It just cannot pack `fs` module, which does not exist. (it's a nodejs module for server-side js, it makes very little sense to import it for client-side code)

Comment: Note that modules written for node.js sometimes require functionality (like writing to tcp sockets or writing to hard disk) that does not exist in browsers. In this case, Winston **cannot be run in browsers** because it requires the `fs` module which is not available in browsers.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up